# AngularJS ng-controller inside an $http response is not working

Tags: angularjs

I have a sample HTML code

```
<div ng-bind-html="model.main_container"></div>
```

And I'm running something like this in AngularJS

```
$http.get("/submit", { cache: true })
    .success(function(data, status) {
        if ( status == 200 ) {      // Success
            $scope.model.main_container = data;
        }
    })
    .error(function(error) {
        if ( error )
            $scope.model.main_container = "Unable to retrieve data";
    });
```

I'm using '`ngSanitize`' that will render the `$http` response into a real HTML code and it's injected fine into the main HTML page.

Problem is, that the HTML response hold AngularJS code, something like:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
  <div ng-click="a()"></div>
</div>
```

But the controller is not really being used by Angular, I assume it because the "a" function ( which simply create a console.log msg ) is not working....

So how do I get the response to work and communicate with my controller ?

( small note, I would like to avoid re-bootstraping it outside of Angular )..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure you can use a scope variable as working HTML, but you need to use the $compile function to make your loaded code work with Angular.

Something like this:

```
$http.get("/submit", { cache: true })
    .success(function(data, status) {
        if ( status == 200 ) {      // Success
            var compiled = $compile(data.data)($scope);                
            $scope.model.main_container = compiled;
        }
    })
    .error(function(error) {
        if ( error )
            $scope.model.main_container = "Unable to retrieve data";
    });
```

Remember to add $compile as a DI.

Comment: mmm , I wonder why you wrote (data.data) ? but data contains that actual HTML string, so the code you provided gave me: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression and listed the HTML string returned ..

Comment: The "data" field that comes back from a $http call contains http codes and such.  I typically name it "response", since that more closely matches what it is.  Then you can do response.data to get the actual data returned.

Comment: As for the unrecognized response, do you have a function named "a()" in your scope?

Comment: The error is not raised when from the response's a() function, it raised from the "var compiled = $compile(data.data)($scope);" line

Comment: To clarify, data.data is undefined in my case, and data is the actual HTML string ...

Comment: I eventually used: https://github.com/francisbouvier/ng_html_compile and changed ng-bind-html to ng-html-compile, removed the ngSanitize from my angular app module list, and added instead "NgHtmlCompile" - worked, but how is that different from your answer ? ( it's a directive fyi )